# Why is scrollview and app moving slow (lagging)

Tags: android, database, image, scrollview, lag

I have a scrollview and in each row I load a picture plus text (the picture path and text are loaded from database). The problem is that if the picture has a very high resolution, the application moves very slow, and when I scroll, it takes a while until it loads, but when I resize the picture, the scrolling becomes fluid. So, the question is: how can I make the app faster? should I load a thumbnail of the picture and load the thumbnail instead of the actual image?

[image: scroll image]

Comment: I guess you answered your own question, thumbnails are the way to go.

Comment: yes, but how do I load a thumbnail? is there a Bitmap.loadThumbnail method ?

Comment: I would recommend shipping the thumbnails as seperate picture-files and not computing them on-the-fly.

Comment: I'd also recommend seperate thumbnails. But if you dont want that, check out BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Resources res, int id, BitmapFactory.Options opts). You can set BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize to >1, this will load a downscaled version of your image.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are loading the contents of the list view on the main UI thread (Reason for the UI to be less responsive). I suggest loading the contents of the list using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Hope this helps you.